# Allowed memory size exhausted + poor performance

Tags: php, mysql

I have `Requests` table in my MySQL database (Yii project), which contains all visits to the main page of my website with

```
fields: `id`, `partner_id` (relation to `Partners` table), `date`
```

`date` with current timestamp.

and `id` with id of a visitor.

The problem is that there is about 1.5 millions rows in the `Requests` table and when I try to expose this data somewhere, it shows poor performance or even error from title.

For example, I've got the list of partners and column called "All requests" where I'm viewing all requests with `partner_id` equal to this partner's id. There could be something like 500 or 1000 requests for every partner, so, I believe, my SQL query is very heavy.

Could you please give some advices about how to make it more flexible?

I still need this data from `Requests` for commercial calculations, but I can't find out how to avoid this huge amount of data and poor performance.

Comment: So what indexes do you have on this table, and what queries are you running against it.... and have you done an EXPLAIN for those queries to see how MySQL is executing them and what indexes it might be using?

Comment: selecting 500 results from a table that size does not seem like a particularly heavy task - as above please show your queries

Comment: I've got 20 User models displayed and for each of them - this query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $requests_table rt WHERE rt.partner_id = t.id

Comment: @Mark Baker I've just used: EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'requests' WHERE partner_id = 1. possible_keys and key are NULL

Comment: So it's not using any keys at all, full table scan.... what indexes do you have on this table? Particularly on the `partner_id` column?

Comment: [Please no!](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2014/06/03/the-problem-is-not-the-tool-itself/)

Comment: Yes, I guess that's it :D added index and 'rows' in EXPLAIN changed from 1680k to 1.4k. Thanks and sorry for newbie questions, I needed to realize it in some way :)

Comment: Remember the CommitStrip cartoon.... it's always useful having a humorous reminder like that for the future.... and the fact that there is a cartoon like that means that enough people make the mistake to know that you're not alone in doing so

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute request 500 or 1000 on a same time. If you do so then it will gives you error or time out error.

Better to put some logic (kind of forloop or foreach) statement and send request in bunch of 10-20 (but not more than that). If you follow this then it will gives you result properly.

Secondly, I don't know about your front end, but suppose you use DotNet then put a call with "async" "await" keyword in your method which handle this kind of task easily.

If you need some more details on this then please revert.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's PHP, Yii framework. I guess, my query runs 20 times, 1 for each partner of the list page (there is a list with pagination in frontend).